# Can wearing a helmet save your life?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

In Grand Theft Auto 5, it is very easy to die while riding a motorcycle. I noticed if you wait a few seconds while on a bike *(make sure you are stationary)*, your character will put on a helmet. If you were to crash, does the helmet protect you from damage or is it pretty much useless?

Comment: It's like these people don't respect that I'm driving on the wrong side of the road doing wheelies and feel the need to crash into me all the time.

Comment: @DoozerBlake ahh yes...those types. I usually leave them a nice parting gift in the form of a sticky bomb before they take off. That'll show 'em. *(evil laugh)*

Comment: It seemed to have an effect in GTA IV. I never properly tested it but I always wore the helmet when I could.

This would be easy enough to test. Find an empty stretch of road where you can drive in a straight line and crash into something. Do it with a helmet, note the damage taken, then do the exact same crash without a helmet.

Comment: @Studoku It did save your life in GTA IV. I can attest to that with certainty. My bike hit a taxi and I flew into a semi, with the helmet I survived (with enough health to scare a rat and die.) but without the helmet, I blended in with the bugs.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

<strike>**It doesn't protect you**

Just found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SD815uEKPtk) Youtube video about GTA 5 Myths.

In this episode they test also exactly your question. And they see, it doesn't protect you.</strike>

**It will protect you**
As the [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sYf3NNXF_t0) in *xan's* answer is shown, it will protect you.

When you search a bit for this question you'll get many videos where you can see it will protect you, other shows it won't protect you.

Just try it by your own.

Comment: Other than the bit where you assume it does, I have no idea what you're trying to say.

Comment: @Studoku: I just describe how you can see that the helmet will protect you...

Comment: I'm really looking forward to GTA Online to try this for a more exact result by using a melee weapon to attack another player being the subject ;)

Comment: In step 3 are you trying to do a dive? For PS3 I'm pretty sure this is achieved by jumping (square) then pressing (circle) in midair. Jumping off a single story building would also be a good test

Comment: Awesome video find! Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Other video's have shown differently. See my answer, or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sYf3NNXF_t0

Comment: This answer is absolutely wrong, as many videos have shown. The accepted answer should be updated.

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt: Your correct. Done.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, the helmet does protect you. See the video here:

These guys originally "Busted" this myth, but it seems that results can be inconsistent depending on exactly how you test this. The conclusion is that it definitely reduces damage, even from gunshots.