# How can I keep myself from flying through the windshield when I get in an accident?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Once in a while I'll run my car into something and I'll go flying through the windshield and die. Other times, I'll ram into something at at even higher speed, stay inside the car, and be just fine.

Is there something that governs whether or not I'm wearing a seatbelt, or is this just random?

Comment: I noticed that the lower your health, the higher the probability you'll fly through the windshield. Either fate's a bitch, or God is :p

Comment: [Always put on your seat belt.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d7iYZPp2zYY)

Comment: Have you ever gone through the windshield and NOT died? I remember this happening in GTA4, but I can't recall it happening in GTA5 yet.

Comment: I've died every time, but I don't know if it's happened enough for me to conclude that's anything more than coincidence. Hell, I've managed to die by running towards a fence and pressing the button to climb it too early, and instead jumping into it, bouncing off, and cracking my skull on the pavement.

Comment: I have gone through the windscreen without dying - it definitely hurt though!

Answer (score 4):

On PC, if you hold <kbd>f</kbd>, the character will buckle up, and won't fly out so easily.

Comment: Was gonna joke that you need to put on your seatbelt. And there it is. There is a  real option to do so. Goddamn GTA.

Answer (score 2):

Well, simply you can't. It's real life physics that when you drive into a solid object with that much force that your body is sent flying. I tried using a roll cage to see if it helps you at all but to no avail.

There are rumors going about that if you wait in the car long enough without driving you put on a seat belt, I'll try to test this theory tomorrow and if it's true I'll edit this question.

Comment: This question refers to motorcycle helmets, and makes the seatbelt theory more credible http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/132052/55704

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to buckle up, even if you sit there he still doesn't buckle up. He will put a helmet on, though. There has been plenty of times I flew through the window and lived.